# Sending audio numpy array to front end Javascript to play sound?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, numpy, flask

Alright so I have this block of code here

```
ipd.Audio(audio[0].data.cpu().numpy(), rate=hparams.sampling_rate)
```

I am trying to use the `audio[0].data.cpu().numpy()` part which contains the audio array data.
I want to send it to the front-end, which I know how. But the problem is I don't know what to do with the data. I have done some research on converting numpy to other forms of data but still pretty lost on how to go about this.

What can I do in the front using JavaScript to turn it into audio. Or better yet using a flask server to redirect it to a get route that returns a mp3 file.

Comment: if you have the mp3, why you want to send raw data (numpy array, iirc)?

Comment: I don't, the numpy array is a result of a generated text to speech numpy array holding audio data

Answer (score 0):

I would start looking into [Audio Buffers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer).

Here is an example I copied from [here](https://mdn.github.io/webaudio-examples/audio-buffer/).
This creates white noise, since we are pushing random values into the audio buffer. Here you have to use your numeric values. Please make sure how to set up the sample rate (should be defined in your python tool)

```html
<body>
    <h1>AudioBuffer example</h1>
    <button>Make white noise</button>
    
  
<script>
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const myScript = document.querySelector('script');


let AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
let audioCtx;

// Stereo
let channels = 2;

function init() {
  audioCtx = new AudioContext();
}



button.onclick = function() {
  if(!audioCtx) {
    init();
  }

  // Create an empty two second stereo buffer at the
  // sample rate of the AudioContext
  let frameCount = audioCtx.sampleRate * 2.0;

  let myArrayBuffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(channels, frameCount, audioCtx.sampleRate);

  // Fill the buffer with white noise;
  //just random values between -1.0 and 1.0
  for (let channel = 0; channel < channels; channel++) {
   // This gives us the actual array that contains the data
   let nowBuffering = myArrayBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
   for (let i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
     // Math.random() is in [0; 1.0]
     // audio needs to be in [-1.0; 1.0]
     nowBuffering[i] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
   }
  }

  // Get an AudioBufferSourceNode.
  // This is the AudioNode to use when we want to play an AudioBuffer
  let source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
  // set the buffer in the AudioBufferSourceNode
  source.buffer = myArrayBuffer;
  // connect the AudioBufferSourceNode to the
  // destination so we can hear the sound
  source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
  // start the source playing
  source.start();

  source.onended = () => {
    console.log('White noise finished');
  }
}
  </script>

</body>
```